# Running MALLET in Java

Tags: java, mallet

I'm trying to run Mallet in Java and am getting the following error.

```
Couldn't open cc.mallet.util.MalletLogger resources/logging.properties file.
Perhaps the 'resources' directories weren't copied into the 'class' directory.
Continuing.
```

I'm trying to run the example from Mallet's website (http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/topics-devel.php). Below is my code. Any help is appreciated.

```
package scriptAnalyzer;

import cc.mallet.util.*;
import cc.mallet.types.*;
import cc.mallet.pipe.*;
import cc.mallet.pipe.iterator.*;
import cc.mallet.topics.*;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Mallet {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String filePath = "C:/mallet/ap.txt";
        // Begin by importing documents from text to feature sequences
        ArrayList<Pipe> pipeList = new ArrayList<Pipe>();

        // Pipes: lowercase, tokenize, remove stopwords, map to features
        pipeList.add( new CharSequenceLowercase() );
        pipeList.add( new CharSequence2TokenSequence(Pattern.compile("\\p{L}[\\p{L}\\p{P}]+\\p{L}")) );
        pipeList.add( new TokenSequenceRemoveStopwords(new File("stoplists/en.txt"), "UTF-8", false, false, false) );
        pipeList.add( new TokenSequence2FeatureSequence() );

        InstanceList instances = new InstanceList (new SerialPipes(pipeList));

        Reader fileReader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(filePath)), "UTF-8");
        instances.addThruPipe(new CsvIterator (fileReader, Pattern.compile("^(\\S*)[\\s,]*(\\S*)[\\s,]*(.*)$"),
                                               3, 2, 1)); // data, label, name fields

        // Create a model with 100 topics, alpha_t = 0.01, beta_w = 0.01
        //  Note that the first parameter is passed as the sum over topics, while
        //  the second is the parameter for a single dimension of the Dirichlet prior.
        int numTopics = 5;
        ParallelTopicModel model = new ParallelTopicModel(numTopics, 1.0, 0.01);

        model.addInstances(instances);

        // Use two parallel samplers, which each look at one half the corpus and combine
        //  statistics after every iteration.
        model.setNumThreads(2);

        // Run the model for 50 iterations and stop (this is for testing only, 
        //  for real applications, use 1000 to 2000 iterations)
        model.setNumIterations(50);
        model.estimate();

        // Show the words and topics in the first instance

        // The data alphabet maps word IDs to strings
        Alphabet dataAlphabet = instances.getDataAlphabet();

        FeatureSequence tokens = (FeatureSequence) model.getData().get(0).instance.getData();
        LabelSequence topics = model.getData().get(0).topicSequence;

        Formatter out = new Formatter(new StringBuilder(), Locale.US);
        for (int position = 0; position < tokens.getLength(); position++) {
            out.format("%s-%d ", dataAlphabet.lookupObject(tokens.getIndexAtPosition(position)), topics.getIndexAtPosition(position));
        }
        System.out.println(out);

        // Estimate the topic distribution of the first instance, 
        //  given the current Gibbs state.
        double[] topicDistribution = model.getTopicProbabilities(0);

        // Get an array of sorted sets of word ID/count pairs
        ArrayList<TreeSet<IDSorter>> topicSortedWords = model.getSortedWords();

        // Show top 5 words in topics with proportions for the first document
        for (int topic = 0; topic < numTopics; topic++) {
            Iterator<IDSorter> iterator = topicSortedWords.get(topic).iterator();

            out = new Formatter(new StringBuilder(), Locale.US);
            out.format("%d\t%.3f\t", topic, topicDistribution[topic]);
            int rank = 0;
            while (iterator.hasNext() && rank < 5) {
                IDSorter idCountPair = iterator.next();
                out.format("%s (%.0f) ", dataAlphabet.lookupObject(idCountPair.getID()), idCountPair.getWeight());
                rank++;
            }
            System.out.println(out);
        }

        // Create a new instance with high probability of topic 0
        StringBuilder topicZeroText = new StringBuilder();
        Iterator<IDSorter> iterator = topicSortedWords.get(0).iterator();

        int rank = 0;
        while (iterator.hasNext() && rank < 5) {
            IDSorter idCountPair = iterator.next();
            topicZeroText.append(dataAlphabet.lookupObject(idCountPair.getID()) + " ");
            rank++;
        }

        // Create a new instance named "test instance" with empty target and source fields.
        InstanceList testing = new InstanceList(instances.getPipe());
        testing.addThruPipe(new Instance(topicZeroText.toString(), null, "test instance", null));

        TopicInferencer inferencer = model.getInferencer();
        double[] testProbabilities = inferencer.getSampledDistribution(testing.get(0), 10, 1, 5);
        System.out.println("0\t" + testProbabilities[0]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Sounds like there's a missing `resources/logging.properties`. Does it use Maven? Ant? Are you building it correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you try to run Mallet either by downloading the version 2.0.8-SNAPSHOT  (https://github.com/mimno/Mallet) or by getting the currently latest maven version (2.0.7) you will get this error.

The reason is that Mallet expects the file logging.properties inside the created `target\classes\cc\mallet\util\resources` folder. When you build the project with maven, this file is not created and therefore this exception occurs in `MalletLogger.java`.

Someone should either configure maven properly so that the logging.properties file is created in the target folder. A temporary solution would be to modify the Mallet code to set another path for `logging.properties`.

Answer (score 10):

Mallet looks for a logging file if one is not specified in the System properties. The simplest way to sort this out if you are using Maven is to put the file in

```
src/main/resources/cc/mallet/util/resources/logging.properties
```

this will copy it automatically has part of the standard Maven build process to:

```
target/classes/cc/mallet/util/resources/logging.properties
```

So you do not need any special configuration. The file can be empty, but it is logically deliberately left out so you configure your own logging.

Comment: Works for Gradle too.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone else who is using Maven and trying to configure Mallet's logging, try this:

Create a new text file at `src/mallet_resources/logging.properties`. It doesn't actually need to specify anything; an empty file is enough to shut Mallet up.

Then modify your `pom.xml` file to make sure that file gets copied to the location mentioned in the other answer. To do this, in the `<build><plugins>` section, add:

```
<!--Mallet logging is horrifically verbose, and has not easy to configure-->
<!--We have to use this complicated process to copy the logging.properties file to the right location -->
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>
                    ${basedir}/target/classes/cc/mallet/util/resources
                </outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/mallet-resources</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the "Couldn't open edu.umass.cs.mallet.base.util.MalletLogger resources/logging.properties file" error, encountered (e.g.) when running run.sh (or or other script or command) in BANNER Named Entity Recognition (uses MALLET).

Solution:

Copy 'logging.properties' from

src/main/java/edu/umass/cs/mallet/base/util/resources/logging.properties

to

target/scala-2.11/classes/edu/umass/cs/mallet/base/util/resources/logging.properties

[I am using the BANNER provided at https://github.com/clulab/banner ]

Another error I encountered at the same time (... Logging configuration class "edu.umass.cs.mallet.base.util.Logger.DefaultConfigurator" failed) can be safely ignored:

https://osdir.com/ml/ai.mallet.devel/2007-11/msg00008.html >> "I think this is a bug with the distribution but that it affects logging only. I've always ignored this warning."

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.ai.mallet.devel/200  >>  "This bug should not affect your output."

http://courses.washington.edu/ling572/winter09/teaching_slides/1_08_Mallet.pptx >> Slide 20: "Please ignore this message." [Fei Xia, Jan 2009, 'Introduction to Mallet', Andrew McCallum's group at UMass (https://people.cs.umass.edu/~mccallum/)]